# How to prevent event propagation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f1(a)
{
alert(a);
document.forms[0].elements[0].focus();
}
function f2(b)
{
alert(b);
document.forms[0].elements[1].focus();
}
</script>
<form name="myform">
<input type="text" name="box1" value="a" onblur=f1('a');  />
<input type="text" name="box2" value="b" onblur=f2('b');  />
</form>
```

The `onblur` event is fired every time and looping indefinitely. I tried `e.stopPropagation()` but still the same.
My purpose is to validate the textboxes when the user navigates to next form element, so this made me to call the function in `onblur()`.

Comment: Try s/t else then `alert`. The `alert` forces any form element to lose focus^^

Comment: Typo?  <script> is missing the end tag, not the problem just a comment.

Comment: Your script forces the focus back on the same element when a `blur()` event occurs. What exactly is your expectation?

Comment: It makes sense that it is looping.  stopPropagation only stops the event from bubbling up to the parent element.  It doesn't deal with the two different events being fired (blur/focus).

Comment: Instead of alert, an excellent way of debugging is installing the Firefox addon Firebug and using the call  `console.log('debug string here')` which logs the string to Firebug's console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an alert popup is opened, and you having to click on it causes the field that you were on the blur once again, which in turn makes another call to one of your functions (f1 or f2), and another alert popup appears. Thus it is an endless cycle. stopPropagation will not help you here. Suggestion: don't use `alert()`.

Now let's assume you didn't call `alert()`. You are still going to have a major usability problem here. After the user initially focuses on either of the text fields, they will never be able to enter the other text field, or any other input element, for that matter, because the initial field will continually require focus.

Answer (score -1):

You could try and troubleshoot this or just leverage an industry proven package, example: jQuery.  It helps you handle all kinds of event propagation and provides nice examples.

Comment: The same code written with jQuery will have the same exact issue.

Comment: It will but I would suggest starting over and stand on the shoulders of giants.

Comment: Oh goodness, don't you think that's a bit overstated? It's just a JavaScript library. Nothing magic. And it certainly isn't appropriate in every situation.

Comment: Depends on the level of developer you are talking about here.  My response makes sense for <2000 hrs of JavaScript development people.  Of course I picked 2000 from the sky, but the point is, stand on the shoulders of giants unless you can't or it gets messy, both of which are not the case here.